# How to Debug Typescript files in Node Application preferably in Eclipse? Which Plugin can I use?

Tags: eclipse, typescript, debugging, eclipse-plugin

I am working on a Node Application with Typescript. I am using eclipse IDE. I would like to know if there is a plugin that allows debugging ts file from Eclipse? I tried CodeMix and Enide plugins but they seem to work when I use "Debug As" for the generated js file, but not for the ts file itself. When I try node --debug-brk and debug from Chrome browser using the url, it works for the js file but when I do the same for ts file, I see the error with import statements.

Any guidance is much appreciated!

Thanks for your time!

I am using the following:

```
Eclipse 2018-12
Node 7.9.0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I debug AngularJS and TypeScript in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25617323/can-i-debug-angularjs-and-typescript-in-eclipse)

Comment: CodeMix can debug TypeScript just fine (will step through the TS source, not JS), but you do need to ensure you compile with sourceMap support. You may need to specify some additional parameters in the debug configuration as well - we do this automatically for Angular projects, but its more difficult to do generically. I realize this response is 5 months too late, but leaving this here for anyone else who stumbles on the same problem. 


Do reach out to us on our [forums](https://www.genuitec.com/forums/topics/codemix/getting-help/) for immediate assistance.